# NativeBase - ReactNative - Dropdown

Tags: android, ios, list, react-native, native-base

Do you have any ideas to how to do that?

A dropdown list opened by clicked on the button and this dropdown list contain a other list of items. And dynamically if it's possible!

For example:
Categories: Fruits, Foods (the first dropdown list)
And in this categories there is a list for each categories :

Fruits : ["Banana", "Apple", "Strawberry"]
Foods: ["1", "2", "3"].

Looks like this :

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I have an idea for you, hope this could solve your problem. For now there is no way to add nested Picker component. So I came up with this idea:

first is restructure the data

```
const data = [
    {'title' : 'Fruits',
    'items' : ["Banana", "Apple", "Strawberry"]
    },
    {'title' : 'Foods',
    'items' : ["1", "2", "3"]}
]
```

next create state toggle for show component while we click the button

```
 constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
      toggleDropdown: false
  }
}
```

next is create function to trigger the state

```
onClickButton = () => {
  this.setState({
      toggleDropdown: !this.state.toggleDropdown
  })
}
```

make button for showing the dropdown

```
<Button primary onPress={this.onClickButton}>
   <Text>Click Me!</Text>
</Button>
```

and show the dropdown

```
{this.state.toggleDropdown &&  //cek if toggle is true or false
            data.map((item, index) => { //loop the first dropdown
                return (
                    <Content key={index}>
                        <Text style={{backgroundColor: '#CCC'}} >{item.title}</Text>
                        <Picker mode="dropdown" > 
                            {item.items.map((value, idx) => { //loop the second dropdown
                                return(
                                    <Item key={idx} label={value} value={idx} />
                                )
                            })}
                        </Picker>
                     </Content>
                )
            })
        }
```

this is the full source code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Content, Text, Button, Picker, Item } from 'native-base';

const data = [
        {'title' : 'Fruits',
        'items' : ["Banana", "Apple", "Strawberry"]
        },
        {'title' : 'Foods',
        'items' : ["1", "2", "3"]}
]

class Example extends Component {
  constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
          toggleDropdown: false
      }
  }
  onClickButton = () => {
      this.setState({
          toggleDropdown: !this.state.toggleDropdown
      })
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <Container>
          <Content>
            <Button primary onPress={this.onClickButton}>
                <Text>Click Me! </Text>
            </Button>
            {this.state.toggleDropdown &&  //cek if toggle is true or false
                data.map((item, index) => { //loop the first dropdown
                    return (
                        <Content key={index}>
                            <Text style={{backgroundColor: '#CCC'}} >{item.title}</Text>
                            <Picker mode="dropdown" > 
                                {item.items.map((value, idx) => { //loop the second dropdown
                                    return(
                                        <Item key={idx} label={value} value={idx} />
                                    )
                                })}
                            </Picker>
                         </Content>
                    )
                })
            }
           </Content>
        </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default Example
```

and this is the screenshot :

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEQil.png)

i hope it can help you :)

Comment: Oh, thanks you for your time and your help! I will check that soon. Thanks you very much

Comment: Hmm I don't think so

Comment: @Erased does my answer is help ?